# Eclipse plugin- compare in custom editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have created a custom editor and want to implement a compare functionality between two files opened using it .
Can anyone suggest how could I achieve that functionality?

Comment: Look at [Compare support](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fcompare.htm) in the Eclipse help. Also the `CompareUI` class.

Comment: I want modify the behaviour of comparison process.It should show difference how beyond compare tool shows.Is there any way that could be achieved.

Comment: Possibly but this is far too broad a question for SO. As I said read all the help on compare support. Look at CompareUI, look at how the compare editor inputs work, look at the differencer and range differencer support.

Comment: Actually I had implemented the compare functionality but comparison results were not that useful.I was not able to get any proper answer for how to rewrite the comparison mechanism .If you get anything new please write back .